# A word for the tipping level of a bottle

Tags: terminology, fluid-statics, surface-tension

Is there a word for the level at which a bottle needs to be filled such that if even a drop of additional liquid were in that bottle and that bottle were placed on its side on a perfectly horizontal surface with its lid removed then that additional drop of liquid will spill out. If that additional drop were not put into the bottle then nothing would spill out?

Comment: Why a "bottle" and why "horizontally"? The question is identical to discussing a glass of water, a bowl of water, or any other container with a simpler, i.e. more "analyzable" shape. A horizontal bottle just complicates a simpler problem with an unnecessarily odd shape.

Answer (score 3):

The water in the bottle exhibits surface tension (due to cohesion between water molecules). This is effectively like a force that pulls water molecules on the surface (the water/air-interface) inward, towards the water.

If you add water droplets to the bottle, the water level and volume will increase and reach over the rim of the opening, but the surface tension will prevent it from spilling out at first (causing the water surface to become slightly dome shaped). As you add more droplets, the overhang will become greater and greater until the water will eventually spill.

If you want to know what that "tipping level" corresponds to? I don't know if there is a word, but I think it will depend on when the gravitational force pulling the overhang of water down/out exceeds the surface tension force pulling water inward. You could call it critical level?